# Returning an object Error

Tags: java

My program seems to not understand what I am trying to do and was hoping if someone could help, I'm getting an error saying I need to return an object but I have three return statements all with different conditions:

```
private Door pickADoor(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    if (i == 2){
      return A;
    }
    else if (i == 1){
      return B;
    }
    else if (i == 0){
      return C;
    }
}
```

A,B and C are all pre-defined objects.

Comment: Where is a,b,c defined? can you post this part of the code?

Comment: *My program seems to not understand what I am trying to do* **totally disagree**... You don't understand how to tell to your program how to do what you need

Comment: @JordiCastilla Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an ELSE statement. Even though you KNOW that only three is possible, the compiler does not know that and it is saying to you "There is probable a case where your method does not have a return statement"

So:

```
 private Door pickADoor(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    if (i == 2){
       return A;
    }else if (i == 1){
       return B;
    }else if (i == 0){
       return C;
    }else{
       return SOMETHING; //somthing here
    }
```

Comment: Or simply remove `if (i == 0)` and let `return C` be the default case

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom that is a solution also, but it would depend on the OP logic, right. Only he knows what he needs everything else is conjecture.

Comment: Quite right. But looking at the code there really are only three possibilities, at least at the moment. And that, I think, is the root of OP's confusion.

Comment: With that, I agree ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a default return statement , since there is no way to be sure that one of your conditions will be met at runtime, and that's why the compiler complains .

```
private Door pickADoor(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    if (i == 2){
      return A;
    }
    else if (i == 1){
      return B;
    }
    else if (i == 0){
      return C;
    }

    return A ; // some default value
    }
```

Comment: Or simply remove if (i == 0) and let return C be the default case

Answer (score 0):

Since the return type of your method is `Door` so, if none of the conditions is true, then it is not returning anything. So you need to add `return null;` at the end of your method. Or you can return some other object in `else` block also.

Comment: The `null` is probably the worst option here. Sure it shuts up the compiler, but it adds nothing to readability and will probably result in a `NullPointerException` in some unexpected spot if it ever actually happens.